# LibreOffice: count distinct values from column

Tags: libreoffice

I have a column with some repeatable values, like color names in a list of a material objects. How could I count a number of each unique value occurrences (e.g. for the 100 rows given there are 5 red, 15 green and 80 black)? I cant use `COUNTIF` since I don't know all the "colors" that may occure.

In SQL-way I would do something like

```
SELECT count(`color`), `color` FROM `MyTable` goup by `color`
```

Comment: At first I misunderstood this question as counting the number of *distinct* values (3 in your example).  Instead, the SQL shows that you are asking about counting *grouped* values.  Perhaps you could edit the title.

Answer (score 15):

A spreadsheet cannot do it as easily as with SQL, but here are two solutions.

**Method 1 - Pivot Table**

Make sure the first row of the column contains a label, for example `Color`.  In the next column, set the label to `Count`.  Enter a count of `1` for all colors.

```
Color  Count
red    1
green  1
red    1
```

Then, select the two columns and go to Data -> Pivot Table -> Create.  Drag `Color` to Row Fields, and drag `Count` to Data Fields.

[image: pivot table]

**Method 2 - Filter**

1. Copy the column data, and paste into column A of a new sheet.
2. Go to Data -> More Filters -> Standard Filter.
3. Change `Field Name` to `- none -`.  Expand `Options` and check `No duplicates`.  Press OK.
4. In B1, enter the formula `=COUNTIF($Sheet1.G1:G100,"="&A1)`.  Change "G" to the column you used on Sheet 1.
5. Drag the formula down.

Links for getting distinct values are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286032/5100564.

Comment: For the pivot table, you don't need the Count column, you can drag `Color` to both Row and Data Fields, then double click it in the Data Fields and select Count instead of Sum: https://superuser.com/a/1614716/98217

Answer (score 2):

Another simple option:

Assumptions:

- Your data is sorted
- For the example below your data is in column A (adjust accordingly).
- For the example below you enter the formula on row 2.

Add a new column with the formula below created on row 2 and copy it to all other rows.

```
IF(A2 == A1, 0, 1)
```

Then you get a `1` in that column ever time a value differs from the row above. Then you can just sum the `1` values:

```
SUM(B2:B?)
```

Your spreadsheet would look like this:

```
 1  "A" | "B" 
 -------------
 2  VALA   1   <-- IF(A2 == A1, 0, 1)
 3  VALA   0
 4  VALA   0
 5  VALB   1
 6  VALB   0
 7  VALC   1
 8  VALD   1
 9  VALD   0
10         4   <-- SUM(B2:B9)
```