# LibreOffice equivalent to SQL "count(*) group by some_column"

Tags: pivot-table, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet

```
A     | B
-----------
alice | 100
bob   | 100
carol | 200
dave  | 100
edith | 200
```

I want to basically `count(*) group by B`, the result being

```
100 | 3
200 | 2
```

How to do this in LibreOffice?

Comment: If you find that the extra power of SQL is needed frequently, use LibreOffice *Base* database, which can execute SQL commands and export to *Calc* spreadsheet https://eeperry.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/libreoffice-base-sql-update-and-delete-records/ , https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/guide/data_im_export.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a pivot table with column B in the "Row Fields" and in the "Data Fields" list; double-click on the "Data Fields" entry "B" to change the default SUM function to Count:

[image]

Result:

[image]